# 2 Onboard Monitor. Will it toast my motherboard?

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-ryzen

I just bought a PC. Here's my setup:

- AMD Ryzen 3 2200G
- Gigabyte A320M S2H Motherboard
- 8 GB RAM
- 1 TB HDD

I'm using dual monitors and they're currently attached on the board. The first is on the VGA and the second is on the DVI.

Will it toast my motherboard/CPU?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you're using a USB-powered display (which generally require a special driver), monitors are self-powered and don't draw power from the display outputs, so the kind of damage you're thinking about won't happen.

The *Raven Ridge* processor allows as many displays to be connected to the processor graphics as the motherboard allows, up to three.

Your display configuration is supported by your hardware. Hardware damage will not occur.

Answer (score 3):

No, having two monitors connected to your computer will not toast it.